# How to Initiate Suspend Mode for a Specific HID Device without Putting Windows 10 to Sleep?

Tags: windows-10, usb, suspend, hid, developer-tools

I have a custom HID (Human Interface Device) and would like to test its behavior when the device is in
**Suspend mode**. I'm seeking a method to initiate Suspend Mode specifically for this HID device on my
Windows 10 PC, **without putting** the entire system to sleep.

Is there a developer tool or any recommended approach to achieve this without affecting the overall
system's power state? Your guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Suspend is a BIOS function and so suspending a portion of Windows without suspending the whole machine is not possible.

Best solution (my opinion) is an expensive machine that you can suspend and test your HID Device. Develop on the main machine.

You can also suspend a Virtual Machine (VMware does this very well and there are other virtualizing apps) and then suspend the HID device in a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can't *suspend* a device, *per se*, but you can easily *disable* it in a few ways:

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type *devm* and select *devmgmt.msc* to open *Device Manager*.

  Select a USB device, right-click on it, and select *Disable device*.
- A USB device can be disabled, and re-enabled, by a [Registry script](https://www.action1.com/how-to-disable-usb-drives-in-windows-operating-systems/). Open *Regedit* to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\`, find the USB device, and set *Start* to *4* to disable it.
- Use a third-party tool, such as Nirsoft's free [USVDeview](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) to enable and disable a device. The tool also has command-line options, and can create a desktop shortcut to perform an action.
- Use [Group Policy](https://woshub.com/how-to-disable-usb-drives-using-group-policy/) to enable or disable a device.